# qt - network based location acquisition

Tags: qt, geolocation, qt-mobility

I need to get geolocation for phones without gps. The only way to do is through mobile network information. I can get few required information like cellid and signal strength for google's api http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI unfortunately its deprecated.

Is there any way in Nokia Qt to get S60 phone location without GPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use Qt Mobility Project API.

In QtMobility package there is a API called "Location".

The Location API provides a library for distributing and receiving location data using arbitrary data sources.

For more details please check this..

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/